# Creating virtual directory tree in zip file using dotnetzip

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am trying to create a zip file from code, I'm using [dotnetzip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com)

I want to create a directory tree in the folder that doesn't exist on disk. How do I do this?

I have tried using `AddDirectory` but this seems to want to find the directory on disk. I have also tried AddEntry but this requires some content.

My files are stored in a SQL Server using the FileStream option and organised in a hierarchy there.

I wrote this recursive method to do it but the AddDirectory line doesn't work.

```
    private void GetFiles(ZipFile zipFile, Folder folder, string path)
    {
        zipFile.AddDirectory(folder.FolderName, path);

        foreach (var file in folder.Files)
            zipFile.AddEntry(file.FileName, file.FileData);

        foreach(var subfolder in folder.SubFolders)
        {
            GetFiles(zipFile, subfolder, path + "\\" + subfolder.FolderName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [AddDirectoryByName](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/html/e96683da-04b7-faef-cca3-e73233b76af0.htm) to create a new directory in the zipfile instead of importing a directory

Answer (score 1):

It seems from their examples page, if you specify the full filel path, it will add an entry in the ZIP corresponding to that path.. therefore you can try just adding the files with full path and skip the AddDirectory step.. At least this is what I could gather from this code sample in their documentation:

**Add a set of items to a zip file, specifying a common directory in the zip archive. This example adds entries to a zip file. Each entry is added using the specified pathname.**

```
 String[] filenames = { "ReadMe.txt", "c:\\data\\collection.csv", "c:\\reports\\AnnualSummary.pdf"};
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AddFiles(filenames, "files");
    zip.Save("Archive.zip");
  }
```

Comment: Anas is right, the new folder name will be created using the second parameter of the AddFiles() method. There's no need to use AddDirectory()